# IPTables which allows inbound connection but disallows inbound traffic

Tags: tcp, iptables

Currently trying to setup **iptables** to allow for a client to connect to the server to listen to a stream of messages via *TCP*. The thing is, we want to block the client from sending any messages once connected (is OK if the client is **DROP**'ed in this case).

Is there a way to allow a client to connect and enforce a 1 way communication from the server to the client only?

Requires this to work purely within **iptables** (no software proxy-like solution).

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem to be solved here is that we can't just shut down *all* the traffic from the client after the connection has been established because TCP is a positive acknowledgement protocol.  If the server does not receive acks from the client, it will retransmit, and eventually time out.  In what follows, I will assume that we are using IPV4.

So what we want to do is to allow the connection to be established, and then only allow acknowledgements from the client, that is, packets that contain no TCP payload.

Unfortunately, the length of the TCP payload is not explicitly represented in the [TCP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure).  We can try to use the overall length in the [IP header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header), but this is complicated by the fact that both the IP header and the TCP header include variable length options fields, so there are many possible overall lengths that ack with no payload.

Since IP options are rarely used and commonly filtered, let's simplify things by first dropping all packets that contain options in the IP header (if your firewall is not already doing so).  The implications of doing so are discussed at length [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-gont-opsec-ip-options-filtering-04).

To do this, we will drop all traffic to our server (here taken to be 10.2.3.4:1234) where the IP header length (bits 4-7 of byte 0 in the IP header) is not 5:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.2.3.4 --dport 1234 \
  -m u32 --u32 "0>>24&0xF=6:0xF" -j DROP
```

This uses the `iptables` `u32` module to grab 4 bytes from the packet starting at byte 0, right shift it 24 bits, mask the lower nibble, and then drop the packet if this is in the range 6-15.  Note that 5 is actually the minimum size of an IP header.

The situation with TCP options is a bit more complicated.  In establishing the connections, many different options may be used, *e.g.*, to negotiate window scaling.  However, once the connection is established, the only thing we need to worry about is TCP timestamps and selective acks.  So let's let the connection be established:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.2.3.4 --dport 1234 \
  --tcp-flags SYN SYN -j ACCEPT
```

Note that it is possible to send a payload in a SYN packet, so here we are not completely meeting your requirement.  Most ordinary TCP implementations will not do so, although [TCP fast open](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7413.txt) does.  If you want to mitigate this, you could drop SYN packets that are fragments (that could reassemble to something very large) and limit the overall length of the non-fragmented SYN packets to something reasonable that would allow for the usual options to be present in the TCP three way handshake.  Note that the above rule was added to the INPUT chain, which is processed *after* IP fragment reassembly.

OK, so we can get the TCP connection established, and the IP headers are restricted to 5 words (20 bytes).

However the TCP headers may contain selective acks, tcp timestamps, both, or neither.  Let's start with TCP headers with no options.  An ack with no options and no payload will consist of a 5 word IP header followed by a 5 word TCP header followed by no data.  So the total length in the IP header would be 40.  If the packet was a fragment, it could conceal a payload in a subsequent fragment, but since we are working with the INPUT chain which is processed after IP fragmentation reassembly, we won't have to worry about this.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.2.3.4 --dport 1234 \
  -m u32 --u32 "32>>28=5 && 0&0xFFFF=40" -j ACCEPT
```

The IP header is 20 bytes and the data offset nibble is in byte 12, so taking the 4 bytes starting at byte 32=20+12, we shift the nibble down and compare it to five, and then make sure that the total length in bytes 2 and 3 of word 0 of the IP header is 40.

If there are TCP timestamps in the TCP header, then there will be an additional 12 bytes (3 words) in the TCP header.  We can accept that in a similar manner:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 10.2.3.4 --dport 1234 \
  -m u32 --u32 "32>>28=8 && 0&0xFFFF=52" -j ACCEPT
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader to work out the other combinations. (Note that dealing with selective ack is several cases as there can be 1-4 selective ack blocks, or 1-3 selective ack blocks with timestamps.)

DISCLAIMER:  I did not actually try this out, so my apologies if there is a typo or if I overlooked something.  I believe the strategy to be sound, and if there is any error or omission, let me know and I will correct.